# How to Turn Laptop Display ON and OFF With a Certain Key?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am looking for a way to turn on and off my laptop screen easily (without it going to sleep or hibernate mode). I have various automation scripts running in the background (which include mouse movement and certain keystrokes), and sometimes I even access my laptop remotely. It's a Windows 10 machine.

I am searching for a way to turn off the display on my laptop (without closing the lid). I tried to set it by using various options available in Windows, but whenever there is a mouse movement, or if I press a key via remote desktop, my laptop's screen turns back on.

I would like it to remain turned off until I press a pre-determined key. For example, I would like to set a hotkey "Ctrl + alt + o", which would turn off my laptop screen. In case there is a mouse movement or key pressed, I would like it to remain off. I would like it to turn back on only when I press "Ctrl + alt + o" again.

I spent a lot of time on a research and tried various solutions, but usually none of them work. Powershell scripts work fine if I need to turn off the screen, but it turns back on as soon as I move the mouse.

Some of the solutions included setting up screen brightness to 0 so it looks like it's turned off, but unfortunately that didn't work for me either. Even if the brightness is set to 0, my screen is still fully visible.

This is very strange since the solution on my old PC which had a monitor would be to simply turn off the monitor by pressing the power button. Is it possible that there is no option to do something like that if you are using laptop?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: _on my old PC ... turn off the monitor by pressing the power button_ Go to Settings - Power Options and Click "Choose what the power buttons do".

Comment: Also, your question is off-topic here. [SU] is a better place to ask.